# How can I call GAP functions from a shell script?

Tags: shell, ipc, child-process, non-interactive, gap-system

I want to get the result of a function of the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) software. This is an interactive command line tool mainly for mathematician who work on group theory related topics.
The documentation/faq states about [8.1: Can I call GAP functions from another programme?](https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.1) that it is in general not possible. However, running GAP as a child process and communicate with it using pipes, pseudo-ttys, UNIX FIFOs or some similar device it can be done.

An example session using a package called CrystCat (Crystallographic Groups Catalog) looks like:

```
$ gap
gap > LoadPackage( "CrystCat" );
gap > DisplaySpaceGroupType( "P1" );
#I     Space-group type (3,1,1,1,1); IT(1) = P1; orbit size 1; fp-free
gap > quit;
$ # exited 'gap' and back in my shell
```

As I am not familiar with these techniques, can someone show me a minimal example having following functionality:

```
$ ./script.sh "P1"
#I     Space-group type (3,1,1,1,1); IT(1) = P1; orbit size 1; fp-free
$
```

**UPDATE:** The accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448468/is-it-possible-to-make-a-bash-shell-script-interact-with-another-command-line-pr) doesn't work.

Comment: Consider using python with https://www.sagemath.org/ which has an interface to GAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer by gap-support (using stdin read-in capability of gap)

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" != "1" ]; then
   echo "Usage: test.sh <string>"
   exit 1
fi;

gap -r -b -q << EOI
LoadPackage( "CrystCat" );
DisplaySpaceGroupType( "$1" );
EOI
```

It works exactly as asked, namely

```
$ ./script.sh P1
#I     Space-group type (3,1,1,1,1); IT(1) = P1; orbit size 1; fp-free
```