# How to expand {} from xargs in process substitution?

Tags: shell, xargs, gap-system

I try to use [`gap`](https://gap-system.org) version 4.10 with `xargs` as following:

```
$ echo 1 | xargs -I '{}' gap -b <( echo 'Display("{}");' ) <( echo 'QUIT;')
```

which returns

```
{}
```

However, it should be

```
1
```

Following works

```
$ gap -b <( echo 'Display("123");' ) <( echo 'QUIT;')
123
```

If you do not have `gap` v4.10, you can replace `gap` with `cat` and still see my problem:

```
$ echo 1 | xargs -I '{}' cat <( echo 'Display("{}");' ) <( echo 'QUIT;')
Display("{}");
QUIT;
```

How can I achieve that the return value becomes?

```
Display("1");
QUIT;
```

From my point of view, this has nothing to do with gap but the combination of xargs and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) in the shell. I have [zsh 5.7.1](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) and [GNU bash 5.0.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) available. xargs is [GNU version 4.8.0](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).

Notes:

- My motivation is that I want to run a gap script in parallel with different parameters from the shell.
- `gap` version 4.10 has not yet the option `-c <expr>` ([commit](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/commit/0bd0966e67529e2fa4edeb67f790c14b6e2ba263)) which would allow me to avoid using process substitution. However, on the compute server, there is only gap version 4.10.0.

Answer (score 2):

The process substitutions themselves resolved to *file names*, not output of the commands inside the substation:

```
$ echo <(echo foo)
/dev/fd/63
```

As a result, `xargs` never sees the `{}`. It reads `1` from its standard input, but none of the arguments to `xargs` contain a `{}`, so no substitution occurs. What you are left with is a single call to `gap` like

```
gap -b /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62  # The exact paths may differ
```

and `gap`, AFAICT, just reads commands from those files and executes them.

If you want to execute the command `Display("1")`, you need to construct that first, *then* execute the result. Something like

```
 # Adjust gap as needed to read from standard input.
echo 1 | xargs -I '{}' echo 'Display("{}"); Quit;' | gap
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner has pointed out, process substitution is performed by the shell before xargs does its {} substitution and so xargs never sees {}.

Creating a shell command as following solved it for me:

```
echo 1 | xargs -I '{}' zsh -c "gap -b <( echo 'Display(\"{}\");' ) <( echo 'QUIT;')"
```

Comment: Just in case, https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/discuss/ has another scenario, when there is a shell script calling GAP (scroll to "Tips and tricks"). On the server, can you install your own GAP? The GAP 4.10.0 version is dated November 2018, more than 2 years old.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link which is also helpful. Actually one could add this as another answer to this question. Regarding the gap version: I tried to install my own gap (version 4.11.1) on the server with linuxbrew. Compilation worked but when I invoke `$ ~/.linuxbrew/bin/gap`, I get the error `Illegal instruction`. I am not sure where to start looking for the reason here. Illegal instruction is not a very specific message.

Comment: Never used linuxbrew - do you mean that you can use https://github.com/gap-system/homebrew-gap with linuxbrew to install on Linux - nice if so! If it does not work, try installing from source as https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/4.11.1.html explains. If that does not work, better to get help by email to [GAP Support](https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html) (I will see it there anyway).

Comment: P.S. I think the recipe from the GAP Carpentries-style lesson is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418849/how-can-i-call-gap-functions-from-a-shell-script

Comment: Hihihihi. I noticed this yesterday evening as well. In my defence it was a long time ago and it got lost in my memory.