# Catch content of command prompt to send different answer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have to set in crontab an sh script that prompts user to answer before executing. But sometimes the question needs "Yes" or "No" answer and sometimes the same script waits for "Force" or "Abort".
I can't modify this script, so i need to make my script to launch the first one, catch the prompt output text and check the prompt text to answer "Yes" or "Force" automatically.
I've tested something like this but doesn't work :

```
if command.sh | grep 'Force' =0
then echo "Force"
else echo "Yes"
fi
```

Thank you for your advices or help :)

Comment: Forgot to say Hi everyone and edit seems not working :-/

Comment: The way to achieve that would be by using fifos. It might not even be possible at all, depending on how `command.sh` was written.

Comment: @Fravadona , i don't know, i don't have access to the code of this command.sh script, i juste need to launch it with a cron job and therefore answer "Yes" or "Force" automatically ...

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25541986/3387716

Comment: @Fravadona I feel that there is an interesting clue there but I am not good enough in shell scripting to adapt to my precise needs :-/

Comment: Can you add samples of what `command.sh` prompts when asking for a reply?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried a simpler solution and it seems working as expected

```
command.sh << EOF
Force

y

EOF
```

Thank for your help